# SQL index/relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm indexing two things of posts. One is the title (words) and two are the keywords. I've chosen to use 3 tables for this:

```
word_index (word,word_id) // al words and keywords are indexed
keyword_rel (word_id,postId) // relations with the keywords
word_rel (word_id,postId) // relations with the the words of the title
```

Now I'm trying to perform a decent search query on this. Using the keywords only, it works fine.

```sql
  SELECT p.postId
  FROM word_index wi
  INNER JOIN keyword_rel kr ON wi.word_id=kr.word_id
  INNER JOIN post p ON p.postId=kr.postId       
  WHERE wi.word LIKE 'input%'
  GROUP BY p.postId
```

But now I would like to include `word_rel` to also search in the title.

I tried this, but it doesn't sound right and also doesn't return everything (missing some of wi.word):

```sql
  SELECT p.postId,wi.word
  FROM word_index wi
  INNER JOIN keyword_rel kr ON wi.word_id=kr.word_id

  INNER JOIN word_rel wr ON wi.word_id = wr.word_id

  INNER JOIN post p ON p.postId=kr.postId 

  INNER JOIN post pi ON pi.postId=wr.postId 

  WHERE wi.word LIKE 'input%'
  GROUP BY p.postId
```

The problem is with `INNER JOIN post p` which is related to `keyword_rel`. Now I also need it related to  `word_rel`. What is a good way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do a UNION here:

```sql
  SELECT p.postId, wi.word
  FROM word_index wi
  INNER JOIN keyword_rel kr ON wi.word_id = kr.word_id
  INNER JOIN post p ON p.postId=kr.postId 
  WHERE wi.word LIKE 'input%'
  GROUP BY p.postId

  UNION

  SELECT p.postId, wi.word
  FROM word_index wi
  INNER JOIN word_rel wr ON wi.word_id = wr.word_id
  INNER JOIN post p ON p.postId=wr.postId
  WHERE wi.word LIKE 'input%'
  GROUP BY p.postId
```

And since this may return some of the results twice or more times (especially if the *word* is contained in both keywords and titles), You may want to wrap the above query into another `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t.post_id, t.word
FROM (
    SELECT ...
    UNION
    SELECT
) t
ORDER BY t.word ASC
```

Comment: This seems to be working but it always sticks with one word even if it should return more than one.

Comment: You mean Your search text is `FOO` and Your query is returning only the post with `FOO` while it should return also the posts with `FOOBAR` and `FOOBARJAR`???

Comment: Seems to be working now. It was something with the post table. Thanks!